# Are there any opensource npm packages to deploy a custom STUN/TURN server?

Tags: node.js, npm, webrtc, stun, turn

I'm building a NodeJS/WebRTC application and was planning to deploy a custom STUN/TURN server. Can anyone suggest me a few npm packages that I can use to setup a custom STUN/TURN server. I was also exploring paid STUN/TURN services. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: There are several STUN/TURN servers freely available online. See https://gist.github.com/yetithefoot/7592580 for example

Answer (score 0):

here you go:

`npm install -g node-stun`

https://github.com/enobufs/stun